# Cannot establish connection with database in PHP using Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I had a simple PHP code to just show if the connection with the database has been established. It has a HTML part, but it seems the connection is not being established. The database used is MySql. The tables are not created as part of the program.

Need some suggestions....

Thank you....in advance.

Here is the code...

```
<h1>LOGIN PAGE </h1>
<form action="" method="post">
Username   <input name="usname" type="text" />
Password <input name="paswd" type="password" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $uname = $_POST['usname'];
    $pswd = $POST['paswd'];
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","archana","details");
    if(mysqli_connect_errorno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to Mysql" ;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "connection established";
    }
    $data = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user");
    while($a = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
    {
        echo $a['username'];
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: Make sure you user and password are correct in mysqli_connect. Also check that details db exists.

Comment: What does the current code echo? Does it display this message?`"Failed to connect to Mysql"`

Comment: `mysqli_connect_errorno()` should be `mysqli_connect_errno()`

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your code based on Marcel Balzer comment

```
<h1>LOGIN PAGE </h1>
<form action="" method="post">
Username   <input name="usname" type="text" />
Password <input name="paswd" type="password" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $uname = $_POST['usname'];
    $pswd = $POST['paswd'];
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","archana","details");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to Mysql. Error: ".mysqli_connect_errno() ;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "connection established";
    }
    $data = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user");
    while($a = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
    {
        echo $a['username'];
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```